# Pulse icon or element color for one minute with javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I would create a pulse color effect with a max duration of one minute. To have this effect with css I can do something like this:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
  50% { background-color: #FFF; }
  100% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
  50% { background-color: #FFF; }
  100% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {
  0% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
  50% { background-color: #FFF; }
  100% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
  50% { background-color: #FFF; }
  100% { background-color: #ed8c55; }
}

.element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ed8c55;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    pulse 3s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      pulse 3s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         pulse 3s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

But in this one I can't control the time. Particularly, I would make this effect in an icon inside a button

```
<md-button aria-label="Info" id="info" title="info" ng-click="openInfo()" class="md-icon-button">
  <i class="zmdi zmdi-help red-color"></i>
</md-button>
```

That `<i />` element should pulse for max one minute in red color. Is this possible do it with angularjs or simply javascript?

Comment: `But in this one I can't control the time` Yes you can, use [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count). As your animation takes 3 seconds, give it a value of `20`. It's not a good idea to  use JS as a crutch for CSS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good to know! Nice, thank you

Comment: No problem. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in this one I can't control the time

You can by using [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count). As your animation takes 3 seconds you can give it a value of `20`:

```
.element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
   background: #ed8c55;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s 20; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    pulse 3s 20; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      pulse 3s 20; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         pulse 3s 20; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```